2D Projection of a 3D Region via Variable Change (Direct Plotting Fails)
The solutions for plotting the 2D projections of a 3D region defined by ImplicitRegion is  here. However, the 3D region of my interest fails to be plotted using ImplicitPlot. So I'm using a change of variables, but then, I'm unsure how to plot the 2D projections of this 3D region.
Specifically, the following code using ImplicitRegion plots the wrong region:
imp = ImplicitRegion[
   Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 - z^2] + Sqrt[x^2 - y^2 + z^2] + 
     Sqrt[-x^2 + y^2 + z^2] <= 1, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}}];
RegionPlot3D[imp, MaxRecursion -> 4, PlotPoints -> 80, Axes -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Opacity[0.4]}, Mesh -> None]

The output of this is the following, which is the wrong region

The correct region can be plotted by the following code:
plot = RegionPlot3D[x + y + z <= 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 4, PlotPoints -> 80, Axes -> False, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Opacity[0.4]}, Mesh -> None];
ncreg = plot /. {x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} -> {Sqrt[y^2 + z^2], Sqrt[
     x^2 + z^2], Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]};

This gives the correct 3D region:

Then, how do I plot 2D projections (without showing the boundaries of the 3D region but only the boundaries of the 2D projections) of this 3D region?
Ideally, it would also be good to get the explicit equations describing the boundaries of the 2D projections.
Thank you!
Edit
The code provided by @cvgmt in their answer using ParemetricRegion works perfectly for the original region that needs to be plotted as mentioned in this post, but it fails to run within a reasonable time for another region that needs to be plotted. I tried to use PerformanceGoal -> "Speed" but it didn't help.
Specifically, the other rejoin I tried to plot is
ParametricRegion[{{Sqrt[y^2 + z^2], Sqrt[(x - z)^2/2 + y^2], Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}[[{1, 2}]], x + y + z <= 1 && {x, y, z} > 0}, {x, 
  y, z}] 


Edit

For the new region.(also work for the original region)

Clear["Global`*"];
expr = {Sqrt[y^2 + z^2], Sqrt[(x - z)^2/2 + y^2], Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]};
indexe = {1, 2};
reg = ImplicitRegion[{0 <= x + y + z <= 1, x >= 0, y >= 0, 
    z >= 0}, {x, y, z}];
bdreg = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@reg;
plot3d = RegionPlot3D[bdreg] /. {{x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} -> expr};
plot2d = 
  Show[RegionPlot3D[
     bdreg] /. {{x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} -> expr[[indexe]], 
     Graphics3D -> Graphics}, Background -> Black];
range1 = PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[plot2d, PlotRange];
imreg = ImageMesh[plot2d];
range2 = RegionBounds[imreg];
plot = RegionPlot[
  TransformedRegion[imreg, RescalingTransform[range2, range1]], 
  BoundaryStyle -> Red, MaxRecursion -> 0]



Set the indexe to {1,2},{1,3},{2,3} respectively.


Original
We can use ParametricRegion+ RegionPlot+BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics+ RegionPlot to get the boundaries of the 2D projections.
reg = ParametricRegion[{{Sqrt[y^2 + z^2], Sqrt[x^2 + z^2], Sqrt[
    x^2 + y^2]}, x + y + z <= 1 && {x, y, z} > 0}, {x, y, z}]
regxy = ParametricRegion[{{Sqrt[y^2 + z^2], Sqrt[x^2 + z^2], Sqrt[
     x^2 + y^2]}[[{1, 2}]], x + y + z <= 1 && {x, y, z} > 0}, {x, y, 
   z}]
regyz = ParametricRegion[{{Sqrt[y^2 + z^2], Sqrt[x^2 + z^2], Sqrt[
     x^2 + y^2]}[[{2, 3}]], x + y + z <= 1 && {x, y, z} > 0}, {x, y, 
   z}]
regzx = ParametricRegion[{{Sqrt[y^2 + z^2], Sqrt[x^2 + z^2], Sqrt[
     x^2 + y^2]}[[{3, 1}]], x + y + z <= 1 && {x, y, z} > 0}, {x, y, 
   z}]

For example, we plot the xy projection.
RegionPlot[RegionPlot[regxy] // BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Red, MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> 100]


Original
Grid[{{ncreg /. {{x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} :> {x, y}, 
     Graphics3D -> Graphics}, ncreg}, {
   ncreg /. {{x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} :> {y, z}, 
     Graphics3D -> Graphics},
   ncreg /. {{x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} :> {z, x}, 
     Graphics3D -> Graphics}}}, Frame -> All]



Thank you very much! Is there a way to remove the lines inside the 2D projections and only show the 2D areas with the boundaries?

Thank you very much for the new solution using ParametricRegion! However, one problem I encountered with ParemetricRegion was that it took forever to plot when I adapted your code for another region. I tried to use PerformanceGoal -> "Speed" but it didn't help.
Specifically, the other rejoin I tried to plot is
    Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}[[{1, 2}]], x + y + z <= 1 && {x, y, z} > 0}, {x, 
  y, z}] ````

I've also edited the question above to include the complications brought by this new region.
